# Dynamically size array?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

Super quick question, my initial thought was this is not going to work, but then I thought why not give it a go. Now I am thinking it won't work as the resultant array does not seem to be properly formed? My question, should this work?

```
NSUInteger numPoints = [[[self dataModel] locationFake] count];
CLLocationCoordinate2D points[numPoints];
```

Comment: My question: Why not just try it?

Comment: I did try it and could not get it to work, I then spotted it in some other code online and that started me thinking. I was pretty sure it would not work, and half expected to get a compile error. But like I say the example online got me thinking ...

Comment: 2nd block of code, lines 2 & 3: http://blog.trentkocurek.com/ios4-map-kit-custom-map-overlays-mkpolyline/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it wouldn't work as the `points[]` array needs to be sized statically.  That is, the compiler needs to know the size of that array, but can't possibly know it until runtime.

If you change it to:

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D *points = malloc(numPoints * sizeof(CLLocationCoordinate2D));
```

That should work.  Just don't forget to `free()` it later when you are done.

Comment: Thank you, that was the way I was going, but just wanted to check. Much appreciated.